# Query involving multiple tables: INNER JOIN excludes some rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have 1 big table with 12 columns , 4 of this columns have fields such as : VersionID , StatusID,Owner ID etc..

I have 3 small tables for Version,Status,etc...this table contain information such as : "VersionID "1 = Active" ; VersionID 2 = Disabled...etc" the same goes for StatusID and OwnerID . 
I created a Query which displays Information from the ,,Big Table" and the information that is contained in the VersionID , StatusID etc. should be displayed from the smaller tables , for example : If In the big table the VersionID displayed is  "1" i want it to show the definition ..in this case "Active".

I managed to do this by using the following code:

```
SELECT 
    Object.Type, Object.ID, Object.Key, Object.IsInactive, 
    Version.Version AS VersionID, 
    Status.StatusText AS StatusID, 
    ObjectDetail.BalancePosition, ObjectDetail.FrequencyID, 
    ObjectDetail.FrequencyTimeLagID, ObjectDetail.ObjectName, 
    ObjectDetail.Description, ObjectDetail.ValueSpecification, 
    ObjectDetail.Computation, ObjectDetail.StorageSystemID, 
    ObjectDetail.StorageSystemField, ObjectDetail.TableFunctionalDatamodel, 
    ObjectDetail.OwnerID
FROM 
    Version 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        [Object] 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            ObjectDetail 
            LEFT JOIN 
            Status 
                ON ObjectDetail.[StatusID] = Status.[ID]
        ) 
            ON Object.ID = ObjectDetail.ObjectID
    ) 
        ON Version.ID = ObjectDetail.VersionID
WHERE (((Object.Type)=0) AND ((Object.ID) Is Null)) 
    OR (((Object.Type)=0) AND ((Object.Key) Is Null)) 
    OR (((Object.Type)=0) AND ((Object.IsInactive) Is Null)) 
    OR (((Object.Type)=0) AND ((Version.Version) Is Null) AND ((ObjectDetail.VersionID) Is Null)) 
    OR (((Object.Type)=0) AND ((Status.StatusText) Is Null)) 
    OR (((ObjectDetail.BalancePosition) Is Null)) 
    OR (((ObjectDetail.FrequencyID) Is Null)) 
    OR (((ObjectDetail.FrequencyTimeLagID) Is Null));
```

This works just fine,the problem is that faulty entries such us "999" for example in the StatusID - "999" has no definition in the small table ..are not displayed. My wish is for the query to display only the fields where there are no entries or entries which do not have a definition in the small table.

Comment: pls format the query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you basically wan't to find rows which have invalid values within their columns?

You can achieve this by using a `left join`, and only including the `null` results:

```
SELECT a.x, b.y FROM BigTable a
LEFT JOIN SmallTable1 b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi,yes this is right .. I tried this : `SELECT VersionID.ObjectDetail, ID.Version FROM ObjectDetail  
INNER JOIN Version  ON Version.ID = VersionID.ID
WHERE VersionID.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Version);` but somehow I get an Error..

Comment: @GordThompson, yeah, I just saw that, will remove it, thanks :)

Comment: This helped , I finally got it :) Thank you.